# Spring, Jpa, Thymeleaf - не отображается шаблон и данные в нем

Tags: java, thymeleaf, spring-jpa

Изучаю Spring, Jpa, Thymleaf.

Не могу открыть шаблон index.html

controller

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import springboottexttask.model.Goods;
import springboottexttask.repo.GoodsRepository;

@RestController
public class GoodsController {
    @Autowired
    GoodsRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        //List<Goods> result = (List<Goods>) repository.findAll();  

        String res = "";
        //repository.findAll().forEach(item->{result.add(item.toString());});
        for (Goods goods : repository.findAll())
            res+=goods.type;

        //ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        //mav.addObject("goods", result);
        //model.addAllAttributes(new Map().put("goods", repository.findAll()) );
        return res;
    }
}
```

repository

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import springboottexttask.model.Goods;

public interface GoodsRepository extends JpaRepository<Goods, Long> {
    List<Goods> findByType(String type);
}
```

model

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Goods")
public class Goods implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7132192019278184663L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "type")
    public String type;

    protected Goods() {

    }

    public Goods(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

src\main\resources\templates\index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test Task</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>List of Goods</h2>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>type</th>
            </tr>

            <tr th:each="item : ${goods}">
                <td th:text="${item.type}">Id</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

почему мне показывается пустая страница? как вывести указанные нужные данные в ней?

Answer (score 2):

Если `ViewResolver` настроен правильно, то

```
@Controller
public class GoodsController {
    @Autowired
    GoodsRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("goods", repository.findAll());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо! так пробовал, но пустая страница. ViewResolver - а что значит правильно?

Comment: Это значит, что Spring [надо настроить](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#views-and-view-resolvers) на поиск шаблонов и обработку их шаблонизатором Thymeleaf.